# Pandas: How to import CSV without the sep="," present at the top of the csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, pandas-datareader

I want to import CSV with pandas. The problem that I have with my CSV is that it has the sep= "," present in the top column, in a few files, due to which the data frame is not constructed properly.

```
Example: 
sep = ,
  Year Dec Jan
     1  50  60
     2  25  50
     3  30  30
     4  40  20
     5  10  10
```

Note: The separator is ALWAYs going to be a ",". I just want it to get removed when I covert the csv to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `skiprows` in `pandas.read_csv()`.

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> skiprowslist-like, int or callable, optional
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.